# ValidationError: User validation failed: password: Path `password` is required., email: Path `email` is required

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I am working with the MERN Stack project and I am trying to create sample user. But when I try to fetch data from backend I got the following error.

> ValidationError: User validation failed: password: Path `password` is required., email: Path `email` is required.
>     at model.Document.invalidate (D:\Github\Ecommerce-mern\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2965:32)
>     at D:\Github\Ecommerce-mern\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2754:17
>     at D:\Github\Ecommerce-mern\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1333:9
>     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
>   errors: {
>     password: ValidatorError: Path `password` is required.
>         at validate (D:\Github\Ecommerce-mern\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1330:13)
>         at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (D:\Github\Ecommerce-mern\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1314:7)
>         at D:\Github\Ecommerce-mern\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2746:18
>         at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {     
>       properties: {
>         validator: [Function (anonymous)],
>         message: 'Path `password` is required.',
>         type: 'required',
>         path: 'password',
>         value: undefined
>       },
>       kind: 'required',
>       path: 'password',
>       value: undefined,
>       reason: undefined,
>       [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
>     },
>     email: ValidatorError: Path `email` is required.
>         at validate (D:\Github\Ecommerce-mern\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1330:13)
>         at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (D:\Github\Ecommerce-mern\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1314:7)
>         at D:\Github\Ecommerce-mern\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2746:18
>         at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {     
>       properties: {
>         validator: [Function (anonymous)],
>         message: 'Path `email` is required.',
>         type: 'required',
>         path: 'email',
>         value: undefined
>       },
>       kind: 'required',
>       path: 'email',
>       value: undefined,
>       reason: undefined,
>       [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
>     }
>   },
>   _message: 'User validation failed'
> }

I tried by changing `required` fiels to `false` but it gives an error again.

Here is my seedRoutes.js file

```
import express from 'express';
import Product from '../models/productModel.js';
import data from '../data.js';
import User from '../models/userModel.js';

const seedRouter = express.Router();

seedRouter.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  await Product.remove({});
  const createdProducts = await User.insertMany(data.products);
  await User.remove({});
  const createdUsers = await User.insertMany(data.users);
  res.send({ createdProducts, createdUsers });
});
export default seedRouter;
```

userModel.js file :

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    isAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: false, required: true },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
export default User;
```

data.js file:

```
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

const data = {
  users: [
    {
      name: 'Vidushika',
      email: 'admin@example.com',
      password: bcrypt.hashSync('123456'),
      isAdmin: true,
    },
    {
      name: 'Tharuni',
      email: 'user@example.com',
      password: bcrypt.hashSync('123456'),
      isAdmin: false,
    },
  ],
  products: [
    {
      //_id: '1',
      name: 'Nike Soccer Football',
      slug: 'nike-soccer-football',
      category: 'Shoes',
      image: '/images/p1.jpg',
      price: 120,
      countInStock: 10,
      brand: 'Nike',
      rating: 4.5,
      numReviews: 10,
      description: 'high quality pair of shoes',
    },
    {
      //_id: '2',
      name: 'Adidas Soccer Football',
      slug: 'adidas-soccer-football',
      category: 'Shoes',
      image: '/images/p2.jpg',
      price: 250,
      countInStock: 0,
      brand: 'Adidas',
      rating: 4.0,
      numReviews: 10,
      description: 'high quality pair of shoes',
    },
    {
      //_id: '3',
      name: 'Nike Slim Pant',
      slug: 'nike-slim-pant',
      category: 'Pants',
      image: '/images/p3.jpg',
      price: 65,
      countInStock: 5,
      brand: 'Nike',
      rating: 4.5,
      numReviews: 14,
      description: 'high quality product',
    },
    {
      //_id: '4',
      name: 'Adidas Fit Pant',
      slug: 'Adidas-fit-pant',
      category: 'Pants',
      image: '/images/p4.jpg',
      price: 25,
      countInStock: 15,
      brand: 'Puma',
      rating: 4.5,
      numReviews: 10,
      description: 'high quality pair of shoes',
    },
  ],
};

export default data;
```

Can I know the error I have done here?

Comment: you are inserting data.products in the User model, that array does not have a password and other filed that's why error is showing

Comment: @swapnilgautam Did you mean in seedRoute.js file? I have used both `data.users` and `data.products` in seedRoutes. Could you please elaborate more in this?

Comment: yes in seedRoutes.js you are inserting the products in User model `  const createdProducts = await User.insertMany(data.products);
`

Comment: Point taken. Thank you very much

Comment: you are welcome; please mark the the below answer as correct if the comment has helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In seedRoutes.js you are inserting the products in the User model

`const createdProducts = await User.insertMany(data.products);`